# Not able to create a package in db2 sql

Tags: sql, db2, package

Hello I was trying to learn db2 sql and I was having some problems.
I want to bind a package, but I don't have any packages to bind.
So when I try to create a package it obviously gives me an error. I know that a package is created when we create a database. But then why doesn't it list any packages when i do 
db2 list packages

I have seen a lot of links but no help. I would really appreciate if someone actually explained it to me.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to understand a package, you first need to understand dynamic and static queries.

Dynamic queries are created at execution time. Everything from PHP, Perl, Python, Ruby or Java (JDBC) are Dynamic queries. For example, when using Java, you get a Prepared statement, and you assign values (setXXX) to the parameter markers (?).

However, there are other programming languages, such as C, Java (sqlj), cobol, where you create the program, with embedded SQL. For example, when using SQLj, you write a class in a .sql file, and the queries are written in specific tags (not java, but started with #sql { }), then you do a precompilation, that is a process where the SQL are taken out from the code, and translated to natural programming language (ie. from sqlj to Java). The SQL in then inserted into a file that is called a bind file. Once you have that, you need to compile the code (javac to create the .class) and bind the file in the database. In this last step is where the packages are created.

A package is a set of data access plans. However, they were calculated at the bind time, not at the execution time, like in the dynamic queries. They are difference between them.

Finally, in order to create a package, you need to change the bind properties, and eventually the bind file itself.

Comment: can u give me an example also?

Comment: Well, this is a complete course at IBM to understand each step in order to know how and why create a package. However, you can read this article (a little old but still accurate) about using sqlj: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0302tsui/0302tsui.html